# Start javascript animation after an image has loaded

Tags: javascript, image, animation

I'm looking for a way to initiate a text animation after a background image has loaded. Specifically, the h1 element should animate after the div#image-bg has loaded it's background image. I'm using [wow.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW) to animate objects and the developer's intention was to initiate movement on scroll. To see the full site where the issue exists, it's all at abbyaker.com.

### Here's a stripped version of my html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Intro - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
        <div id="headwrap">
            <div id="image-bg"></div>
            <div id="intro">
                <h1 class="white wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="400ms">Hello</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
     new WOW().init();
    </script>
</body>
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: I would try `<body onload="function() { new WOW().init(); }">`

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct notification for the loading of a background image.

One work-around is to load it into a javascript image object and when that image reports that that same image is loaded, you will know that your background image is also available.

Another work-around is to use the page's `window.onload` handler to know when all page resources are loaded.

Here's how the first would work:

```
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function() {
     // place code here for when the background image is loaded
 }
 img.src = "url of background image";
```

The second option would be like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
     // place code here for when the background image is loaded
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to detect if the background image that is set by CSS has finished loading. You can do that with a plugin called [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages).

You do like this.

```
$('div#image-bg').waitForImages({
    waitForAll: true,
    finished: function() {
        //do animation here.
    }
});
```